Add extra properties to iceberg table using Trino
I want to add custom properties to iceberg table using Trino (v449) so they are visible in metadata $properties table. Below code does not work.
alter table catalog_nessie.test_database.test_table set PROPERTIES 'myKey' = 'myValue'

There are some properties that can be modified as they are defined [here] and it's also possible to add comment that will be visible in metadata table (only in Trino).
alter table catalog_nessie.test_database.test_table set PROPERTIES format = 'ORC'

comment on table catalog_nessie.test_database.test_table is 'Comment text'

Using PySpark I can do below and the table property myKey is going to be visible in metadata $properties table.
spark_session.sql('ALTER TABLE nessie.test_database.test_table SET TBLPROPERTIES ("myKey" = "myValue")')

Is it possible to do this directly with Trino?
